# How do I write an extension type that wraps pre-allocated data?

Tags: python, c, cython

I have some data from a struct that has already been allocated and initialized. 
I can guarantee that the data will not be freed during any of these objects lifetimes. How do I wrap this in a Python object in Cython? The following does *not* work, but I hope it explains my intent:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc

ctypedef struct Point:
    int x
    int y

cdef class _MyWrapper:
    cdef Point* foo
    def __cinit__(self, Point* foo):
        self.foo = foo

def create_eternal_MyWrapper(int x, int y):
    cdef Point* p
    p = <Point*>malloc(sizeof(Point))
    p.x = x
    p.y = y
    return _MyWrapper(p)
```

The output from running cython on this:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
def create_eternal_MyWrapper(int x, int y):
    cdef Point* p
    p = <Point*>malloc(sizeof(Point))
    p.x = x
    p.y = y
    return _MyWrapper(p)
                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

examplecy.pyx:17:23: Cannot convert 'Point *' to Python object
```

Comment: What is `MyAllocatedData`? A C struct? A `cdef class`? A kind of Python object?

Comment: A C type. Specifically, a struct. Do you want the exact struct definition in C and Cython?

Comment: I don't think those details matter. But *how* does it "not work"? Can you provide a [better](http://sscce.org/) example?

Comment: @delnan That's fair, sorry. I've put up a complete example now.

Comment: the problem is not in the way you allocate the data, but in the way you pass the pointer to the constructor. Passing NULL pointer will result in the same error

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](http://en.usenet.digipedia.org/thread/15907/5608/), both `__init__` and `__cinit__` methods use `PyObject_Call` API function, which can only accept PyObject typed arguments. So, as suggested also in [FAQ](http://wiki.cython.org/FAQ#CanCythoncreateobjectsorapplyoperatorstolocallycreatedobjectsaspureCcode.3F), you should initialize C-attributes inside your global factory method:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc

ctypedef struct Point:
    int x
    int y

cdef class _MyWrapper:
    cdef Point* fooless
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise TypeError("This class cannot be instantiated from Python")

cpdef _MyWrapper create_MyWrapper(int x, int y):
    cdef _MyWrapper w = _MyWrapper.__new__(_MyWrapper)

    cdef Point* p
    p = <Point*>malloc(sizeof(Point))
    p.x = x
    p.y = y

    w.foo = p

    # initialize all other fields explicitly
    # ...

    return w
```

One can of course create a dedicated initialization method in `_MyWrapper` itself, but I think that would be rather unsafe because user can forget to call such method after the class is instantiated.

PS: would be nice to see if there exists a simpler solution